# kv filter in logstash

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-configuration

How does remove_field in kv work? I have a json file and need to remove fields that are deeply nested in the json file.

[url][queryString][404;http://hspb.homesearch.com:80/wcJV4LhTSmzJ1rX6FOq4RuiKe K49gUP2JvWtjdhhE] is one such field

This filter doesn't work in logstash

```
 filter {
   kv {
      source => [ "[url][queryString]" ]
      remove_field => [ "404;%{somefield}" "my_extraneous_field" ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove_field will remove the named field(s) when the underlying filter (in your case 'kv') succeeds.

If you need to refer to nested fields, try "[foo][bar]".  You can test if you can use fields in the variable names...

NOTE: [foo][bar] is meant to illustrate how to refer to nested fields.  If your fields are [myTopField][myNestedField], use that.

Comment: kv will succeed if it's able to take your input and split it apart.  In that case, remove_field will fire.  If it can't process your input, remove_field won't fire.

Comment: What is %{somefield}, "my extraneous field"..Also if the file is json. Will source as [foo][bar] work with the interested key inside it?